# Cannot configure docker-compose as an interpreter in PyCharm

Tags: docker-compose, pycharm, remote-debugging, mwaa

I have a problem with configuration of Docker-compose as a remote interpreter in PyCharm. Inside of "Services" section I can select only "services" or "networks".

[image]

I am using this docker-compose file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws/aws-mwaa-local-runner/main/docker/docker-compose-local.yml

Comment: Please edit the question to include the error messages as text. Consider [these reasons and guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either disable "Docker Compose V2" experimental feature in "Docker for Windows" app settings or update PyCharm to [2021.2.1 RC](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=23004355). See the relevant ticket in PyCharm's issue tracker - [PY-49305](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-49305).

[image]